# How to test for blocking when setting O_NONBLOCK flag of message queue

Tags: posix, message-queue

How to test for blocking when using mq_send( ), after setting O_NONBLOCK flag of message queue?

Is it something like this

```
if (errno == EAGAIN)

  printf("Blocking occured\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You use the `mq_getattr` call.

```
int mq_getattr(mqd_t mqdes, struct mq_attr *attr);
```

(2) This returns the struct mq_attr which looks like this:

```
       struct mq_attr {
           long mq_flags;       /* Flags: 0 or O_NONBLOCK */
           long mq_maxmsg;      /* Max. # of messages on queue */
           long mq_msgsize;     /* Max. message size (bytes) */
           long mq_curmsgs;     /* # of messages currently in queue */
       };
```

(3) Test for whether O_NONBLOCK is set e.g.

```
if (mystruct.mq_flags & O_NONBLOCK) //nonblocking
```

---

You may be asking something else.  If you want to know if `mq_send` worked after you set the queue nonblocking then you have the right idea.  If the call didn't work (because the queue was full and you would have blocked waiting for it to have room for your send) then the call will return -1 and errno will be set to EAGAIN.  This doesn't mean "blocking occurred" it means *blocking would have occurred but didn't* because the queue is in nonblocking mode.  So you have to try the send again later when hopefully the call will succeed.